# Symfony - PHPunit Submit form with jquery-generation of values (for selects)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, symfony

I have a problem with PHPUnit functional test for symfony2.

I have some forms with selects, and their values are not necessarily set in the formtype, but generated by Jquery.

For example : 
A FormType Contain :

```
class MyType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
    $builder
        ->add('zipCode',    'text')
        ->add('city',       'choice', array('choices' => array('' => ''), 'mapped' => false))
        ->add('way',        'choice', array('choices' => array('' => ''), 'mapped' => false));
    }
}
```

In my View, the user set the ZipCode, and with AJAX request I set the option for city, and next for way.

Usually, I get/submit form like that :

```
$form = $crawler->selectButton($submit)->form();
$form['nameOfZipCodeField'] = 'VALUE';
$form['nameOfCityField'] = 'VALUE';
$form['nameOfWayField'] = 'VALUE';
$crawler = $client->submit($form);
```

But, the values for the Way and City isn't set in the formType so, phpunit say something like : VALUE is not a possible value (possible value : )

It's logical... but i don't know how to do.
I tried to set the inputs values directly (by filter() method from Crawler) but i cant simulate the click on a button (not a linkl, a button).

If You have an answer, I'm open :)
Thank's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this :

```
$form = $crawler->selectButton($submit)->form();
$form['nameOfZipCodeField'] = 'VALUE';
$form['nameOfCityField']->disableValidation();
$form['nameOfCityField'] = 'VALUE';
$form['nameOfWayField']->disableValidation();
$form['nameOfWayField'] = 'VALUE';
$crawler = $client->submit($form);
```

> By default, choice fields (select, radio) have internal validation activated to prevent you from setting invalid values. If you want to be able to set invalid values, you can use the disableValidation() method on either the whole form or specific field(s).

**Read the docs**: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html#selecting-invalid-choice-values

Comment: I think some explanation to your code will be useful for many SO users.